# How to use any application on the command-line?

Tags: windows, pdf, pdfcreator

There is this software called doPDF which can convert images, word, poweropoint, excel files into pdf. http://www.dopdf.com/

How do I make use of this awesome tool in the command line so that I can call it from PHP in order to convert files into pdf format.
If you know other alternatives which can run on the command line then it's also accepted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn`t find an option with ~dopdf~, but I know two tools that could solve your problem:

[- PDFForge:](http://www.pdfforge.org/content/command-line-parameters)

> PDFCreator enables you to create documents via the command line
>   interface. Here are the different commands that PDFCreator supports.
>
> Example: pdfcreator.exe /PF"C:\help.doc"

[- CommandLinePDF:](http://www.commandlinepdf.com/)

> Print PDF documents from your command line! With a few simple command
>   line options you can fully control your PDF printing from any tool or
>   application.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the PHP PDFlib Library to create PDF files through PHP.

> The PDF functions in PHP can create PDF files using the PDFlib library which was initially created by Thomas Merz

[Read all about it](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php), etc...